# Create python map based on bash output

Tags: python, bash, dictionary

How can I pass this output into a python map object?
Basically, I'd like to be able to run something similiar to `print data.Data` in the python script.
So that on the terminal, all that will be printed is

```
'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This is my python script:

```
[root@server tools]# cat remoteTest.py
import sys

data = sys.stdin.read()
print data
```

This is how I will run the command:

```
[root@server tools]# staf server2.com PROCESS START SHELL COMMAND 'uname' WAIT RETURNSTDOUT STDERRTOSTDOUT | python remoteTest.py
Response
--------
{
  Return Code: 1
  Key        : <None>
  Files      : [
    {
      Return Code: 0
      Data       : 'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you control the output of `staf`?  A better choice of output formatting (it looks somwhat similar to a JSON already) would make it a lot easier.

Comment: I do not, `staf` output is beyond my control. It will always follow this format

Comment: Your best chance is to try to convert the "almost json" part into a format that `ast.literal_eval` can parse, which means surrounding the keys (Return Code, Key, Files, etc.) and all other string values in quotes, and putting commas between each map entry. This would be pretty hard to do in a generic way, but if you can make certain assumptions about the formatting of the output from staf, it's probably doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested only in line

```
Data       : 'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

You can use [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to call staf program

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(["staf", "server2.com PROCESS START SHELL COMMAND 'uname' WAIT RETURNSTDOUT STDERRTOSTDOUT"])
```

and use regular expression. I don't like of regex, but sometimes it is needed.

```
result = re.findall(r'Data\s+:\s+(.*)', output, re.M)[0]
print result
```

*Edited*
with information of multline staf program output

```
output = output.replace('\n', '')

result = re.findall(r'Data\s+:\s+(.*)}', output, re.M)[0]
```

**Edited**

```
o = """{
   Return Code: 1
   Key        : <None>
   Files      : [
     {
       Return Code: 0
       Data       : 'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.

     }
   ]
 }"""
a = o.replace('\n', '')
import re
print re.findall('Data\s+:\s+(.+?)\}', a)[0].strip()
```

Comment: this did not work, `File "/root/Python-2.7.6/Lib/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['staf', "server2.com PROCESS START SHELL COMMAND 'uname' WAIT RETURNSTDOUT STDERRTOSTDOUT"]' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: Maybe you have to pass every parameter separated. subprocess.check_output(['staf', 'server2.com',  'PROCESS', 'START', 'SHELL', 'COMMAND', "'uname'", 'WAIT', 'RETURNSTDOUT', 'STDERRTOSTDOUT'])

Comment: After separating each parameter, this is response. Notice is does not contain all the output: `'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: @bobbyrne01 It's because there's a '\n' in the middle of the output, which is screwing up with regex. It's probably also what's screwing up my answer. I assumed that the output was all on one line.

Comment: @dano yeah output may contain new lines, you can see that in sample staf comannd output

Comment: Try to remove '\n'from output and change regex to terminate in '}'. output = output.replace('\n', '') result = re.findall(r'Data\s+:\s+(.*)}', output, re.M)[0]

Comment: @andmart output = subprocess.check_output(['staf', 'server2.com', 'PROCESS', 'START', 'SHELL', 'COMMAND', "'uname'", 'WAIT', 'RETURNSTDOUT', 'STDERRTOSTDOUT']) output = output.replace('\n', '') result = re.findall(r'Data\s+:\s+(.*)}', output, re.M)[0] print result .. outputs the  following result: `}  ] program or batch file.an internal or external command,`

Comment: @andmart your edited answer does not work either, output: `[root@server ~]# python remoteTest.py operable program or batch file.an internal or external command,`

Answer (score 0):

This works for your sample. It's got some hackery to handle the nested array, which means it won't work if the nested array isn't outputted exactly like this:

```
Key: [
  <Nested content>
```

There's probably some other minor changes to the input that will break it, but its a start, at least.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ast 

a = """ 
Response
--------
{
  Return Code: 1
  Key        : <None>
  Files      : [
    {
      Return Code: 0
      Data       : 'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

    }
  ]
}"""

lines = a.split("--------")[1].split('\n')
new = []
for line in lines:
    if ":" in line:
        # If the line is a mapping, split it into the part before and after the ":".
        parts = [l.strip() for l in line.split(":")]
        # Surround strings in double quotes.
        s = ': '.join(['"%s"' % i if not i.startswith("[") else i for i in parts])
        # Add a comma if it's not an embedded list.
        if not s.endswith('['):
            s += "," 
        line = s 
    if line:
        new.append(line)

d = ast.literal_eval('\n'.join(new))
print d['Files'][0]['Data']
```

Output:

```
dan@dantop:~> ./parse.py 
'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: how do you suggest I load data into the python script instead of a hardcoded string?

Comment: @bobbyrne01 You can use the `sys.stdin.read()` approach you showed in your example. You could also use the `subprocess` module to call `staf` from the script directly.

Comment: Using `data = sys.stdin.read()` and replacing `a` with `data` from your exmaple, I get `Traceback (most recent call last): File "remoteTest.py", line 23, in <module> d = ast.literal_eval('\n'.join(new)) File "/root/Python-2.7.6/Lib/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval') File "/root/Python-2.7.6/Lib/ast.py", line 37, in parse return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST) File "<unknown>", line 8 operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @bobbyrne01 I'd need to see the complete Traceback to say what's wrong. Probably something minor with the way data is formatted vs. a.